# Прерывается доступ к сайту после запроса от NodeMCU v2 (ESP8266)

Tags: api, esp8266, micropython, nodemcu

NodeMCU должен подключаться к точке доступа, посылать запрос к API на сервере и получать оттуда команду для включения/выключения освещения. Но после первой попытки подключения получает ошибку ECONNABORTED, после чего доступ к API невозможно подключить с любого устройства, подключённого к роутеру.
С мобильного интернета/другого роутера запросы не блокируются

Код запроса:

```py
def get_sleep():
    print('Get sleep command...')
    command = urequests.get(url=URL + 'ds/', headers=header).json()
    mode = command["deep_sleep"]
    if mode == "off":
        pass
    else:
        deep_sleep(command["duration"])


def run_command(turn=1):
    do_connect(True)
    get_sleep()
    time.sleep(1)
    if turn == 1:
        command = get_command()
    else:
        command = get_mode()
    if command:
        print(command)
        time.sleep(1)
        change_mode(command)
    else:
        pass
    do_connect(False)
    time.sleep(8)
```

Код ошибки:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 95, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 78, in run_command
  File "main.py", line 51, in get_sleep
  File "urequests.py", line 162, in get
  File "urequests.py", line 100, in request
OSError: [Errno 103] ECONNABORTED
```

Comment: Распишите настолько подробнее, насколько можете. «Невозможно подключить» - какая ошибка возникает? Получается, что на конкретном роутере в итоге не удаётся подключиться с любого устройства, даже не NodeMCU?

Comment: И покажите, каким образом производится запрос в коде

Comment: Судя по ошибке, у вас падает в методе get_sleep, а вы добавили метод get_mode. Я предполагаю, что вы слишком часто шлете запрос на сервис, и вас блокируют по ip.

Comment: Да, пропадает возможность подключения к серверу с любого устройства на роутере. После перезагрузки роутера доступ есть до того момента, как к серверу попытается подключиться NodeMCU

Ошибку и код добавила в пост

Comment: @insolor Методы аналогичные, падение происходит при вызове любого. Ожидание между запросами стоит в одну секунду, так что вряд ли проблема в частоте. API писала сама, каких-то ограничений по запросам, кроме как от  хостинга, нет, но те ограничения не нарушаются

Comment: Попробуйте сделать как по ссылке, которую Андрей скидывал делать close для результата запроса, что-то типа такого: https://pastebin.com/rb7pPsJC

Comment: Прошу прощения, удалил, посчитав не совсем уместной - [ссылка](https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=5094)

Comment: @insolor Добавила close, нет изменений

Comment: А API на чем сделано? Может в логах сервера что-то видно будет?

Comment: @insolor API на flask, после ошибки запросы перестают доходить до сервера с этого роутера. Скорее всего проблема на уровне провайдера, но не совсем ясно, как исправить

Comment: А провайдер какой? Даже на каком-нибудь pythonanywhere можно посмотреть логи подключений клиентов и ошибок сервера. На других скорее всего тоже. Попробуйте в логах посмотреть, там может станет что-то понятнее.

Comment: @insolor провайдер dom.ru, хостинг springhost, в логах при возникновении econnaborted не записано ничего, до этого всегда 200, то есть запросы вообще не доходят до сервера

Comment: А если локально тот же API запустить, будет стабильно работать или тоже глючить?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в использовании бесплатного домена, предоставляемого хостингом.